# How to retrieve remote_user from ldap_auth?

Tags: authentication, nginx, ldap

I'm using two containers, one for nginx and one for the ldap-auth. Both are from the dockerhub and can be found on linuxserver.io. I'm new to nginx and started to give it a try. I would like to use the login name from LDAP in my nginx default.conf so that i can proxy_pass to a different service dependent on the login.

This is my default.conf:

```
# redirect all traffic to https
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

# main server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name webtoptest.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    include /config/nginx/ldap-server.conf;
    
    location / {
        include /config/nginx/ldap-location.conf;
        
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
    
        set $upstream_proto http;
        set $upstream_port 3000;
        

                Pseudocode:
                if (ldap_login = test) {
                   set $upstream_app webtop1;
                }
                if (ldap_login = test2) {
                   set $upstream_app webtop2;
                }
        
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
# enable proxy cache for auth
proxy_cache_path cache/ keys_zone=auth_cache:10m;
```

and this is the example ldap-server.conf:

```
location /ldaplogin {

    set $upstream_auth_app ldap-auth;
    set $upstream_auth_port 9000;
    set $upstream_auth_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_auth_proto://$upstream_auth_app:$upstream_auth_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Target $request_uri;
}

location = /auth {

    set $upstream_auth_app ldap-auth;
    set $upstream_auth_port 8888;
    set $upstream_auth_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_auth_proto://$upstream_auth_app:$upstream_auth_port;

    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";

    #Before enabling the below caching options, make sure you have the line "proxy_cache_path cache/ keys_zone=auth_cache:10m;" at the bottom your default site config
    proxy_cache auth_cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
    proxy_cache_key "$http_authorization$cookie_nginxauth";

    # As implemented in nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py, the ldap-auth daemon
    # communicates with a LDAP server, passing in the following
    # parameters to specify which user account to authenticate. To
    # eliminate the need to modify the Python code, this file contains
    # 'proxy_set_header' directives that set the values of the
    # parameters. Set or change them as instructed in the comments.
    #
    #    Parameter      Proxy header
    #    -----------    ----------------
    #    url            X-Ldap-URL
    #    starttls       X-Ldap-Starttls
    #    basedn         X-Ldap-BaseDN
    #    binddn         X-Ldap-BindDN
    #    bindpasswd     X-Ldap-BindPass
    #    cookiename     X-CookieName
    #    realm          X-Ldap-Realm
    #    template       X-Ldap-Template
    # (Required) Set the URL and port for connecting to the LDAP server,
    # by replacing 'example.com'.
    # Do not mix ldaps-style URL and X-Ldap-Starttls as it will not work.
    proxy_set_header X-Ldap-URL "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389";

    # (Optional) Establish a TLS-enabled LDAP session after binding to the
    # LDAP server.
    # This is the 'proper' way to establish encrypted TLS connections, see
    # http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html
    #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Starttls "true";

    # (Required) Set the Base DN, by replacing the value enclosed in
    # double quotes.
    proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BaseDN "dc=example,dc=com";

    # (Required) Set the Bind DN, by replacing the value enclosed in
    # double quotes.
    # If AD, use "root@test.local"
    proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BindDN "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";

    # (Required) Set the Bind password, by replacing 'secret'.
    proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BindPass "password";

    # (Required) The following directives set the cookie name and pass
    # it, respectively. They are required for cookie-based
    # authentication. Comment them out if using HTTP basic
    # authentication.
    proxy_set_header X-CookieName "nginxauth";
    proxy_set_header Cookie nginxauth=$cookie_nginxauth;

    # (Required if using Microsoft Active Directory as the LDAP server)
    # Set the LDAP template by uncommenting the following directive.
    #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Template "(sAMAccountName=%(username)s)";

    # (Optional if using OpenLDAP as the LDAP server) Set the LDAP
    # template by uncommenting the following directive and replacing
    # '(cn=%(username)s)' which is the default set in
    # nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py.
    proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Template "(uid=%(username)s)";
    # (Optional) Set the realm name, by uncommenting the following
    # directive and replacing 'Restricted' which is the default set
    # in nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py.
    #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Realm    "Restricted";
}
```

I tried the $remote_user variable, but the value was never set. I tried a map because I heard that ifs are not the way to go, but same result. I heard that the value of $remote_user is only set when http authentication is used, but how can i get the name from the ldap login?